# php: how do i insert values into database from multiple dropdown list and added one text along with it

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have two table' displayed its data with 2 drop-down list so i want to add those selected value from both dropdown list and want to insert one Question(text) and one radio button value along with it! 
plz help me am little bit confuse :/ how to do with it ?

here is code

```
<div class="grid_10">
        <div class="box round first">

            <h2>Add / Edit Questions </h2>
            <p>         
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_5">
        <div class="box round">
            <h2>
                Add / Update Questions</h2>
            <div class="block">
                <p>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr> 
    <td>
        <h2>Select Designation</h2>


<?php       

        $sql = "SELECT desg_name FROM 360d_designation";
        $ds = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<select>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ds)){
        echo "<option value='".$row["desg_id"]."'>".$row["desg_name"]."</option>";
        }mysql_free_result($ds);
        echo "</select>";



    ?>  

     </td>
    <td>        
        <h2>Select Relation 
        </h2> 
        <?php
            //<select id="id" name="selectstate" onChange="showCity(this.value)">
            $sql = "SELECT rel_name FROM 360d_relations";
            $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<select>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
            echo "<option value='".$row["rel_id"]."'>".$row["rel_name"]."</option>";
            }mysql_free_result($rs);
            echo "</select>";  
            //$rel = $row;
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Enter Question :

### Mode of FeedBack

Point Scale  
            Description

```
    <?php 


    if(isset($_POST["btns"])){                                      //<-----Inserting data in to databse

        $que_id = $_POST['que_id'];
        $Que_detail = $_POST['Que_detail'];
        $desg_id = $_POST['$ds'];
        $rel_id = $_POST['$rs'];
        $feedback_type = $_POST['$c1'];
        $msg="";                
        if($que_id==0) 
          {
            $q = "insert into 360d_app_questions values(null,'{$Que_detail}','{$desg_id}','{$rel_id}','{$feedback_type}')";
            $msg = "added";
          }
        else        
          {
            $q = "update 360d_app_questions set Que_detail ='{$Que_detail}' where que_id=".$que_id;
            $msg = "updated";       
          }
        $res = mysql_query($q,$con);
        if($res)
            echo "<h2>Question {$msg} sucessfully!!</h2>";
        else
            echo "question cannot be {$msg}";                       
     }



?>

    </center>



    </p>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_5">
        <div class="box round">
            <h2>View Questions </h2>
            <div class="block">                    
                <p> 


                <?php                       
    /*              $qry = "select * from 360d_app_questions ";
                    $res = mysql_query($qry,$con);
                    if($res && mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
                    echo "<table cellspacing=10>".
                    "<tr><th><h2>Questions Manager </h2></th><th><h2> &nbsp &nbsp  Edit</h2></th><th></th></tr>";
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                    echo "<tr>".

                    "<td><h2>$row[1]</h2></td>".

                        "<td><a href='360d_addquestions.php?dept_id={$row[0]}'> <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;✉ <?php ?></h2></a></td>".
                    "</tr>";


                    }
                    echo "</table>";
    */          ?>







                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your title question you should give your both select a name, like

```
<select name="test">
// Options here
</select>

<select name="test_2">
// Options here
</select>
```

To insert some other text on DB we could achieve that from diferent ways, one is in you select  tag do something like:

```
echo "<option value='".$row["rel_id"]." / Details'>".$row["rel_name"]."</option>";
```

and where you threat data sent over form you could use:

```
$exploded = explode('/', $_POST['test']);
```

Then you can concatenate

Or you can insert your text while inserting in DB like:

```
"INSERT INTO tableName(columnName) VALUES (value1+ ' ' + detail)"
```